# Index setup for Search Attribute table in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a database that has many tables. In this database, there are a subset of tables that store information for similar (but distinct) rows of data, and one table that contains common search attributes that can be applied to each table.

There are 18 columns of searchable variables, and I'm not sure which is the best way to set up the indexes. Do I create a single `Index` for all the pertinent columns, or one `Index` for each one?

Comment: u use a search index engine, like SOLR, and not MySQL

Comment: @ItayMoav sadly, not an option. Not my server so can't do anything fancy like that :(

Answer (score 0):

As u can not use SOLR or similar.
You need to emulate this, using MySQL.
To do so u create one table which u de-normalize all other tables into it. Do notice, this table does not replace the other ones. Consider it like a VIEW.
For a simple example. I have a product, and that product can come in several color codes.
Normalization requires me to have 3 tables. One for product, one for colors (name|code) and one table to link them all.

Denormalize it into one table: product code (pk) |name| color code 1|color name 1| color code 2 | color name 2 ..... No I believe it will be easy for u to decide what to index (really based on the queries you do on that table).

Obviously it isn't optimal, but, you need to play with the toys u have.

Something else to consider, which is **very** similar, is using star schemas